# parse error in maybe divide (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, option-type

Just a simple question that i cannot solve
I was trying to get maybe_divide by the following code as assignment required, however terminal give me an error message

> test2.hs:1:112: Parse error in pattern: (Just x)

```
maybe_devide :: Maybe Float -> Maybe Float -> Maybe Float
maybe_devide maybeX maybeY = case maybeX maybeY of
  (Just x) (Just y)
    |x/=0 && y/=0 -> Just (div x y)
    |x=0 && y/=0  -> Just 0
    |x/=0 && y=0  -> Nothing
  Nothing (Just y) -> Nothing
  (Just x) Nothing -> Nothing
```

Who likes to tell me what is wrong with it?
Thanks

Comment: `maybeDivide mx my = do x <-mx; y <- my; guard (y /= 0); return (div x y)`

Comment: Why `x=0` as a special case? And by the way, it should be `==`.

Comment: haha, that's an accident, i changed that right after i post this question,

Comment: @augustss, sry man, i didn't go this far in haskell, so i've no idea about return and <-, my stupidity  X(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`maybeX maybeY` is applying the function `maybeX` on the argument `maybeY`, whereas you are intending to do case analysis on the the pair `(maybeX,maybeY)`. Also you should use `==` for equality and not a single `=`. The following will do what you intend:

```
maybe_devide :: Maybe Float -> Maybe Float -> Maybe Float
maybe_devide maybeX maybeY = case (maybeX,maybeY) of
  (Just x,Just y)
    |x/=0 && y/=0 -> Just (div x y)
    |x==0 && y/=0  -> Just 0
    |x/=0 && y==0  -> Nothing
  (Nothing,Just y) -> Nothing
  (Just x,Nothing) -> Nothing
```

Alternatively you could make use of the `Maybe` monad, as in

```
maybe_devide :: Maybe Float -> Maybe Float -> Maybe Float
maybe_devide maybeX maybeY = do
        x <- maybeX
        y <- maybeY
        case (x,y) of
                (0,y) -> Just 0
                (x,0) -> Nothing
                (x,y) -> Just (div x y)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, however, when i try ur version of maybedevide, terminal shows the following error massage                                         "[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test2.hs, interpreted )
test2.hs:1:251: parse error on input `->'
Failed, modules loaded: none"

Comment: sry man, it take ages to insert a new line, I tried ENTER but that will post the comment instead

Comment: Hmm. Different version of `ghc` maybe. You could try augustss' version instead. Actually I also get an error on using `div` on `Float`.

Comment: haha, my bad, that should be Integer, ive changed it already XD

Comment: Should be `x / y` instead of `div x y`.  `div` is for `Integral` types, and `/` is for `Fractional` types.  Also, the `(0, y)` case is unnecessary since it's already covered by the final case.

Comment: yea, i know man, i accidentally put Float instead of Integer, My Bad  XDD